# According to the Catholic Church, is belief in trinitarianism required for salvation?

Tags: catholicism, trinity

According to the Catholic Church, is belief in trinitarianism required for salvation?

Note: this is not asking whether trinitarianism is true, or whether a valid baptism is required, but whether one must believe in trinitarianism for salvation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**According to the Catholic Church, is belief in trinitarianism required for salvation?**

Most certainly yes, as from even before the Nicene creed was formulated, candidates for baptism were required to answer several questions to profess belief in the Trinitarian God.

From [today's Rite of Catholic Baptism](https://www.bedfordcatholic.org/documents/2015/5/RiteOfBaptism.pdf) (Parents and Godparents answer on behalf of the infant; same answers are expected for adult initiates):

> ...
>
> CELEBRANT: Do you believe in God, the Father almighty, creator of heaven and earth?
>
> PARENTS AND GODPARENTS: I do.
>
> CELEBRANT: Do you believe in Jesus Christ, his only Son, our Lord, who was born of
> the Virgin Mary, was crucified, died, and was buried, rose from the dead, and is now seated at the right hand of the Father?
>
> PARENTS AND GODPARENTS: I do.
>
> CELEBRANT: Do you believe in the Holy Spirit, the holy catholic Church, the communion of saints, the forgiveness of sins, the resurrection of the body, and life everlasting?
>
> PARENTS AND GODPARENTS: I do.
>
> ...

Also, the [Catholic Catechism](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s2c1p2.htm) clearly teaches this:

> **232** Christians are baptized "in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit"⁵³ Before receiving the sacrament, they respond to a three-part question when asked to confess the Father, the Son and the Spirit: "I do." "The faith of all Christians rests on the Trinity."⁵⁴
>
> ⁵³ Mt. 28:19
>
> ⁵⁴ St. Caesarius of Arles, Sermo 9, Exp. symb.:CCL 103,47.

**Yes, but even if the wording of the a baptism involves holding to trinitarianism (I'm not sure it does given the wording above, TBH) most Catholics are baptized as infants, and so their beliefs aren't the ones being verified.** (from comment)

Correct, but if we examine the whole context of the Rite of Baptism linked above, there is an expectation from the Parents to teach the child the Catholic faith:

> CELEBRANT: You have asked to have your child baptized. In doing so you are accepting the responsibility of training him (her) in the practice of the faith. It will be your duty to bring him (her) up to keep God's commandments as Christ taught us, by loving God and our neighbor. Do you clearly understand what you are undertaking?
>
> PARENTS: We do.

Therefore, when the child is old enough to take first communion, a common way for Catholic parents to discharge their promise is to give the child a mini catechism such as what [this article](https://www.catholiccompany.com/magazine/3-ways-to-spiritually-prepare-your-child-for-first-communion-6025) describes using a popular text such as [Saint Joseph First Communion catechism](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/pdf/5807) containing clear teaching of the Trinity suitable for 1st-2nd grade kids.

From Lesson 3 titled "The Blessed Trinity":

> **10. Is there only one God?**
>
> Yes, there is only one God.
>
> ```
>  There cannot be more than one God.
>  There never will be more than one God.
> ```
>
> **11. How many Persons are there in God?**
>
> In God there are three Persons -- the Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost
>
> ```
>  The Father is God.
>  The Son is God.
>  The Holy Ghost is God.
>  But they are all ONE God.
>  The Father is the First Person.
>  The Son is the Second Person.
>  The Holy Ghost is the Third Person.
>  There are THREE Persons in ONE God.
> ```
>
> **12. What do we call the three Persons in one God?**
>
> We call the three Persons in one God the Blessed Trinity.
>
> [there is even a picture, see page 16]
>
> [image: page 16]
>
> **13. How do we know that there are three Persons in one God?**
>
> We know that there are three Persons in one God because we have God's word for it.
>
> ```
>  The Father sent His Son to us on earth
>  The Son told us what the Blessed Trinity is like.
>  The Blessed Trinity is God's family.
>  But it is a family which is all one God.
>  In this family all is love.
>  They never fight.
>  They always agree.
>  They are always happy.
>
>  Say this prayer often: O God, make my family holy.
> ```

**Can you clarify how these aspects of baptism impinge on the question of whether one must believe in trinitarianism for salvation?**  (from comment)

I understand that as adults we can ask theologically and philosophically complicated questions and I do appreciate how great Christian theologians *cum* philosophers like St. Thomas Aquinas can develop whole systems of thoughts to plumb the depth of the Trinitarian doctrine from God's side (as mystery) and from our side (through reason).

But when it comes to **salvation** it is a highly PRACTICAL matter to undertake the LIFE of faith through the sacraments of the church, and in order to fully incorporate those sacraments (the primary being the Eucharist) into someone's spiritual life, the most basic assumption about God needs to be there for those sacraments to even make sense.  For example: if Jesus is not in essence God, the Catholic eucharist rite is tantamount to idolatry!  Hence the custom of First Communion catechism that I deliberately quoted at length above to show how even the most uneducated person should have no problem understanding it.

As you can see in the [Catholic Order of Mass](http://catholicfaith.co.uk/downloads/orderofmass.pdf) there is the reciting of the creed (step 18) prior to the Communion Rite (starting at step 124).  The expectation is to prepare our hearts to receive communion properly, which includes regarding the host to be the **real presence of Jesus**.  If we do not believe in Trinitarianism, then taking communion would amount to sacrilege which is mortal sin.  Reciting the creed with doubts is okay as long as we give the church a chance to explain.

**Similarly, even someone baptized as an adult might change their views.**  (from comment)

The moment a baptized Catholic deliberately refuses to believe that God is Trinity, in the eyes of the Catholic Church, the person has committed the sin of heresy or apostasy.  See [my answer to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/80766/10672).  As I explained in the answer, there is a big difference between having doubts and acting on them.  It is fine asking difficult questions about the Trinity (as I do myself), but while asking those questions, the PRACTICAL matter (the one that the Catholic Church sees as very important to shepherd her faithful) is whether the spiritual LIFE is healthy.  She does it through issuing and enforcing practical regulations on church practice.

Comment: Yes, but even if the wording of the baptism involves holding to trinitarianism (I'm not sure it does given the wording above, TBH) most Catholics are baptized as infants, and so their beliefs aren't the ones being verified. Similarly, even someone baptized as an adult might change their views. Can you clarify how these aspects of baptism impinge on the question of whether one must believe in trinitarianism for salvation?

Comment: The wording of the rite reads to me as if God is identified with the Father, not Jesus - if anything, and just reading what is quoted here, it sounds non-trinitarian! There's God = the Father, then there's Jesus, God's Son, and then there's the Holy Spirit.

Comment: "The moment a baptized adult no longer believes that God is Trinity, in the eyes of the Catholic Church, the person has committed the sin of heresy or apostasy." Am I following this correctly as "Not believing in trinitarianism = heresy" and "heresy = no salvation"?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg Yes (BTW I modified the wording to emphasize the deliberateness of the unbelief).  That's how critical Trinitarianism is in the eyes of the Catholic church.  But as I explained at length in the other question, the church recognizes that doubt is NOT sin.  It's very important to see life of faith as not primarily intellectual, but **volitional**.  It's what we do that matters; in the mass there is the reciting of the creed, so the question is whether we can recite it in good faith.  Reciting with doubts is okay as long as we give the church a chance to explain.

Comment: Am I to understand, then, that according to the Catholic Church there is no salvation for all Protestants and Orthodox since they are in heresy? Or is it something more specific to this kind of heresy?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg As I explained in the Variations section of [my answer to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/80766/10672) although Protestants and Orthodox beliefs are technically "heresy", out of charity the Church doesn't call them "heretics" anymore, esp. since all 3 branches subscribe to the Nicene creed. As apologist Dave Armstrong [explained](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/davearmstrong/2016/04/do-catholics-excommunicate-people-to-hell.html) the Church has no power to condemn anyone to hell. Her goal is to protect her faithful by labeling certain beliefs "heresy".

Comment: @TurkHill This is how I do it: 1) First and foremost I have to realize that God's essence is beyond all human understanding and it is sheer arrogance to put God in a concept that we (creatures created by God) can understand; 2) God revealed Himself in history culminating in Jesus's incarnation, so human reasons DO have a basis to understand parts of God's essence He showed to us, and that's how the early church fathers came up with the definition of Trinity, which is NEVER MEANT to be exhaustive, but enough to separate true faith (apostolic) from false faith (those already labeled as heresies)

Comment: @TurkHill 3) By "reasons have a basis" I meant reason employed to synthesize BOTH revealed truths (that humans cannot came up on our own) AND truths that human reason can come up on its own (because reason is created by God in the first place).  The Trinitarian definition is a synthesis of both sources, a creation of the church fathers who came up with the Nicene creed.  Further details of the synthesis were created by St. Augustine and St. Thomas Aquinas in their respective theologies.

Comment: So is there a specific church document that separates out this heresy from other heresies that Protestants and Orthodox engage in, that makes clear a difference in salvation?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg This is my personal view that I find helpful.  The Catholic church sees herself as protecting the "deposit of faith" from misrepresentation and corruption.  The church documents throughout history served as authoritative **interpretation** of this deposit which began with the NT, continuing with the council documents such as those from Nicaea, Chalcedon, etc.  The church documents are *interpretation*, NOT *full definition*, since portion of this deposit, like the Trinity, is a mystery.  The church has no authority to define more than what God chose to reveal.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg In every age there were prominent threats starting with the Gnostics in the 2nd century to certain elements (not all !) of Protestant theologies dealt with in the documents produced by the council of Trent.  More councils & their documents will keep coming because new threats will keep coming. The Church then serves as a beacon in the sea of confusion in every age so the faithful has bearing to complete our journey to heaven (see Lesson 1.3 as the purpose of the whole book). Bearing = necessary but incomplete truths for our salvation, including our incomplete understanding of God.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg So to answer your question: "is there a specific church document that separates out this heresy from other heresies that Protestants and Orthodox engage in, that makes clear a difference in salvation", my personal view is that *earlier* age dealt with *greater* threats to corruption of the deposit of faith, so the results of the council of Nicaea is far more fundamental than the differences of the nature of justification that the Catholic church dealt with at Trent.  As I implied, it's not specific church document but more like progressive refinement.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thank you for your comments but I forget the context or why you are writing to me. It appears my comment was deleted. Could you please explain the context of what I wrote before your response. In short, I agree with you.

Comment: +1 for a bold answer!  From one of your comments:  "The church has no authority to define more than what God chose to reveal."  Dogmas of Mariology leap to mind here.

Comment: @MikeBorden Thanks.  I try to answer from within the logic of Catholicism, where to some extent overlaps with all Trinitarian denominations who value the Nicene creed and the concept of the [deposit of faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposit_of_faith).  In Catholic logic, the 4 Marian dogmas are [divinely revealed](https://udayton.edu/imri/mary/d/dogmas-marian-overview.php) although not explicitly stated in the NT. Yes, I do recognize Protestants who hold the *sola scriptura* position do not agree with categorizing Marian dogmas as divine revelation, but that's a question for another day.

Answer (score 5):

St. Thomas Aquinas addresses exactly this question in [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 2 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS002.html#SSQ2A8THEP1) ("**Whether it is necessary for salvation to believe explicitly in the Trinity?**"), answering (co.):

> It is impossible to believe explicitly in the mystery of Christ, without faith in the Trinity, since the mystery of Christ includes that the Son of God took flesh; that He renewed the world through the grace of the Holy Ghost; and again, that He was conceived by the Holy Ghost. Wherefore just as, before Christ, the mystery of Christ was believed explicitly by the learned [e.g., [Abraham and Moses](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59561/1787)*], but implicitly and under a veil, so to speak, by the simple, so too was it with the mystery of the Trinity. And consequently, when **once grace had been revealed, all were bound to explicit faith in the mystery of the Trinity**: and all who are born again in Christ, have this bestowed on them by the invocation of the Trinity, according to [Mt. 28:19](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=28&l=19-#x): "Going therefore teach ye all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son and of the Holy Ghost."

<sup>**A fortiori*, [St. Paul knew the doctrine of the Trinity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/68439/1787).</sup>

Comment: "all were bound to explicit faith in the mystery of the Trinity" By this does St. Aquinas mean that salvation requires belief in trinitarianism? Saying someone is 'bound' to a belief seems different than saying that belief is required for salvation, but I just might not be understanding the terms here.

Comment: Also, is St. Aquinas' Summa church doctrine?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg Yes, now that Jesus Christ revealed the doctrine by becoming incarnate, one must believe in the Trinity. Four truths are absolutely necessary to believe for salvation: (1) "that he [God] is", i.e., that God exists; (2) that He "is a rewarder to them that seek him." ([Heb. 11:6](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=65&ch=11&l=6-#x)); (3) Incarnation; (4) Trinity. {cf. [_True or False Pope_](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5904) p. 113 // PDF p. 128.}

Comment: @AnthonyBurg "_is St. Aquinas' Summa church doctrine?_" See "[Are Catholics required to accept every article of Aquinas's «Summa Theologica»?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50214/1787)" (Note: There is unanimous consent among Catholic theologians that truths #1 and #2 in my previous comment are absolutely necessary to be explicitly believed, but not all theologians (St. Thomas Aquinas, St. Alphonsus Liguori, et al. excepted) believe explicit belief in truths #3 and #4 is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The Trinity is a Dogma of the Catholic Church

> 1 THE creed which is called Apostolic is composed essentially of (1) a Trinitarian part, three articles professing faith in three divine persons; (2) a Christological part which was added to the first section.
>
> [Denzinger](http://patristica.net/denzinger/#n1)

All Dogmas of the Catholic Church must have the full "obedience of faith" by Catholics

> "The Roman Pontiff, head of the college of bishops, enjoys this infallibility in virtue of his office, when, as supreme pastor and teacher of all the faithful - who confirms his brethren in the faith he proclaims by a definitive act a doctrine pertaining to faith or morals... . The infallibility promised to the Church is also present in the body of bishops when, together with Peter's successor, they exercise the supreme Magisterium," above all in an Ecumenical Council. When the Church through its supreme Magisterium proposes a doctrine "for belief as being divinely revealed," and as the teaching of Christ, the definitions "must be adhered to with the obedience of faith." This infallibility extends as far as the deposit of divine Revelation itself.
>
> Catechism of the Catholic Church 891

There is no salvation outside the Catholic Church

> If someone from this people wants to be saved, let him come into this house so that he may be able to attain his salvation. . . . Let no one, then, be persuaded otherwise, nor let anyone deceive himself: Outside of this house, that is, outside of the Church, no one is saved; for, if anyone should go out of it, he is guilty of his own death
>
> Origen

Therefore all Catholics must believe in the Trinity to be saved.

---

HOWEVER, and not exactly pertinent to the question, but worth noting, what the meaning of [No Salvation outside the Church](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/print-edition/what-no-salvation-outside-the-church-means) is.  It doesn't necessarily mean everyone else is damned, it just means that if you are saved, it'll be by Christ's saving grace and "The grace necessary for salvation continues to come from Christ, through his Church."

---

Lastly, check out the [Athanasian Creed](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02033b.htm)

> He therefore that will be saved, must thus think of the Trinity.

Comment: So there *is* salvation outside of the Church, and so someone who is non-trinitarian *can* have salvation? I'm confused how to understand this.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg at the very least, I think it means, if you meet a non-Trinitarian in Heaven, he or she is not there because they were a non-Trinitarian.

Comment: Is this on par with other dogmas of the church that, say, Protestants, or Orthodox, do not agree with?

Comment: "it just means that if you are saved, it'll be through grace" Aren't we all saved through grace, according to Catholicism?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg not at all, the lack of a Trinitarian formula in the rite of Baptism invalidates the sacrament.  This is why Protestants and Orthodox don't need to be "rebaptized" when they enter the Catholic Church.  And no, I wrote that wrong, saying "through grace" is probably too vague. It should be "by grace" not "through grace"

Comment: What is the trinitarian formula in the Catholic rite of Baptism?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg "I baptize you in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit" which comes straight out of Matthew 28:19

Comment: That doesn't sound trinitarian to me. No mention of Jesus being God. I think many unitarians would be completely comfortable with that.

Comment: How can a sentence with 3 subjects in the Bible not reflect the Trinity?  Anyway, I have no idea how unitarian baptism works, so [I asked this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81092/how-do-unitarians-interpret-the-great-commission-matthew-2816-20)